# Rails - Simple Loop Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I am trying to do a bulk insert into a table, in my first attempt it works but the names somehow get mangled as the following: (loop runs 24 times which is what I want)

`test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4

test-port-name-0-1-2

test-port-name-0-1-2-3

test-port-name-0

test-port-name-0-1

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22

test-port-name-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23`

instead of `test-port-name-0 .... test-port-name-23`

```
def bulk_port_import
  if request.post?
    #attempt create
    count = 0
    for i in 1..session[:no_ports]
      params[:dp][:name] = params[:dp][:name] + '-' + count.to_s
      @dp = DevicePort.create params[:dp]
      count = count + 1
    end
  end
 @success = "Saved." if @dp.valid?
  @error = ""
  @dp.errors.each_full {|e| @error += e + ", "}
  redirect_to '/device/update/' + params[:dp][:device_id]
end
```

Different attempt:

```
def bulk_port_import
  if request.post?
    #attempt create
    i = 0
    while i < session[:no_ports] do
      params[:dp][:name] = params[:dp][:name] + '-' + i.to_s
      @dp = DevicePort.create params[:dp]
      i++
    end
  end
  session.delete(:no_ports)
  @success = "Saved." if @dp.valid?
  @error = ""
  @dp.errors.each_full {|e| @error += e + ", "}
  redirect_to '/device/update/' + params[:dp][:device_id]
end
```

but with this I get `syntax error, unexpected kEND` and I can't see what I'm doing wrong in either case, it's probably something stupid, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are changing params[:dp][:name] in the loop

```
def bulk_port_import
  if request.post?
    #attempt create
    count = 0
    for i in 1..session[:no_ports]
      dp_name = params[:dp][:name] + '-' + count.to_s
      @dp = DevicePort.create(params[:dp].merge(:name => dp_name))
      count = count + 1
    end
  end
  @success = "Saved." if @dp.valid?
  @error = ""
  @dp.errors.each_full {|e| @error += e + ", "}
  redirect_to '/device/update/' + params[:dp][:device_id]
end
```